# Xamarin Forms Entry Change flow direction issue for Arabic language

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, right-to-left, left-to-right

We are using a placeholder for entry. While I am changing language English to Arabic entry text working left-to-right, but entry placeholder working right-to-left. How to change entry placeholder FlowDirection left-to-right in xamarin forms android and ios.

Comment: According to [this issue at github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3359), this should have been fixed in Xamarin.Forms version 4.6.0. Verify that you have that version or higher: Solution Explorer / Nuget Manager / Installed - find Xamarin.Forms - what version does it say is installed in your solution (or project)? any updates listed for that?

Comment: I am using latest xamarin forms version 5.0.0.2012

Comment: Is the problem that the page starts with a left-to-right language, and then user selects Arabic?  That is, if the language is already Arabic when the page is first created/viewed, does it work?

Comment: The default language is English. User selecting English to Arabic getting a problem. Also the language is already Arabic when the page is first created/viewed not working

Comment: Sounds like its still bugged. As a test, explicitly set `entry`'s `FlowDirection`, either in XAML or code-behind cs:  `FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft`. If this works correctly, then you'll have to set it dynamically depending on language. Could do that via a Binding. If that doesn't work, then the only way to fix it yourself is via a `custom renderer`. You could try to find the renderers for `Entry` in Xamarin Forms sources at github. The final alternative is to go to the issue I linked, download project from first post, build and run. If it has same symptom, add a comment there.